# Почему файлы, состоящие из большого количества нулевых байтов, копируются быстрее, чем нормальные в NTFS?

Tags: ntfs

Файлы, состоящие из большого количества нулевых байтов, копируются быстрее, чем  нормальные. Почему?
Система ntfs. Файл не sparse.
Диск не сжат. Файл не сжат. Скоро копирования в среднем в 2.4 раза быстрее. Для любых объемов. OS win10 64.

Comment: Каковы результаты замеров? Объём данных, и время записи файла из нулевых байт и не нулевых?

Comment: ОС какая? (и как вы определили, что файл не sparse?)/ Скорее всего ОС перед записью распознает нулевые блоки и реально не пишет их на диск (т.е. все же у вас получаются sparse файлы)

Comment: B:\experiment>fsutil sparse queryflag 10mb
У этого файла НЕ установлен атрибут "Разреженный"

Comment: @grolx24, т.е. у вас все же винда (в подобных вопросах **всегда** поишите, ***какая ОС***)

Comment: Реальная система или виртуалка?

Comment: А как вы замеряли, может быть этот файл у вас к кеше уже был, а другой - нет.